# Customize Interactive grid toolbar with a new button to send mail

Tags: button, report, oracle-apex, customization

I have a requirement to have a custom button appear in the Interactive Grid (IG) toolbar area, and upon clicking this button it should send email based on the various status change that the user will do by using a select list in the report.

Following various resources, I have been able to customize my IG toolbar to include my new button but I am not sure how I can achieve the processing part i.e. to get the IDs & Status changed rows and then pass the IDs of these rows to an action which is linked to the pressing of the new button.

Comment: Hi Ashi, did you still need help with this or did Monica’s answer work? If it worked, please accept the answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript Initialization Code to extend the IG functionality.
If the user can select which rows are going to be changed, you can include this code in JavaScript Initialization Code attribute:

```
var i, records, model, record,
      view = apex.region("ig_emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");
    var selectedIds = [];
    if (view.supports.edit)
    {
      model = view.model;
      records = view.getSelectedRecords();
      if (records.length > 0)
      {
        for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
        {
          record = records[i];            
          selectedIds.push(records[i][0]);
        }
```

Then you can execute a PL/SQL Code for those selected rows, for example:

```
          apex.server.process ("PRD_FAV_EMP", 
                               {x01: JSON.stringify(selectedIds)},
                               {dataType: 'text', 
                                success: function( pData )
                                {        
                                    //Refresh IG - Favorite Employee (Optional)                                     
                                    apex.region("ig_fav").refresh();
                                }
                               }
                              );
```

in your case would send a mail.

To read the full example where the button is created in the IG and how the button links the action, please go to [Extending interaction to Interactive Grids - Part II](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/extending-interaction-to-interactive-grids-part-ii).

To run a sample app:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=extending_ig

Comment: How can I perform this functionality on the existing save button of the report?